# Alternative way to prove isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

If $\alpha, \beta $ are two complex numbers with the same minimal polynomial (of degree $n  $, say), then $\Bbb Q  (\alpha)$ and $\Bbb Q (\beta) $ are isomorphic in the natural way.

I know how to prove it: the elements of $Q  (\alpha ) $ can be written as a sum $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} c_i \cdot \alpha^i$. Then by compuations one can check the axioms of morphism.

Is there a way to prove the theorem with less computations and more abstract thinking ?

Comment: I assume that you mean $\mathbb Q(\beta)$, as $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ is obviously isomorphic to $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ in a very natural way.

Comment: Haha indeed ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f$ be the minimum polynomial. Then both $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ and $\mathbb Q(\beta)$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb Q[x] /(f)$. Hence they are isomorphic.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a link to the proof that property?

Comment: This is the first isomorphism theorem (for rings). Consider the map from $\mathbb Q[x]$ to $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ that sends $x$ to $\alpha$. What is the kernel?

Comment: In particular you should be able to see easily that the above (as in the last comment) map is surjective and its kernel is the ideal $(f)$. Then it is just the statement of the first isomorphism theorem (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1027300/proof-of-the-first-isomorphism-theorem-for-rings)

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!